# how to parse a <a> href(s) in string with image tags

Tags: javascript, image, replace, href

```
 function replaceTextFunction(g){
        var replacedText,replacePattern1,replacePattern2,replacePattern3;
        replacePattern1=/(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;
        replacedText=g.replace(replacePattern1,'<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');
        replacePattern2=/(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
        replacedText=replacedText.replace(replacePattern2,'$1<a href="http://$2" target="_blank">$2</a>');
        replacePattern3=/(([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.])+@[a-zA-Z\_]+?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+)/gim;replacedText=replacedText.replace(replacePattern3,'<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>');
        return replacedText;
        }
```

ok so i have me this function. Its purpose is to parse links in strings and put pretty wrappers for human clicking. It works great in that regard.

My problem is when I have an image in the string like this

```
<img src="http://yada.yada/image.jpg">
```

it parses like this

```
<img src="<a href="http://yada.yada/image.jpg" target="_blank">">
```

and of course I do not want that syntax horror to occur. Please help! :(

Comment: what are you doing img to anchor or anchor to img?

Comment: Only use your parser to check text inside of Tags (e.g. `<p>http://</p>`, not in attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function replaceTextFunction(g){
        var replacedText,replacePattern1,replacePattern2,replacePattern3;
        replacePattern1=/(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])(?![^<]+>)/gim;
        replacedText=g.replace(replacePattern1,'<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');
        replacePattern2=/(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))(?![^<]+>)/gim;
        replacedText=replacedText.replace(replacePattern2,'$1<a href="http://$2" target="_blank">$2</a>');
        replacePattern3=/(([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.])+@[a-zA-Z\_]+?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+)(?![^<]+>)/gim;replacedText=replacedText.replace(replacePattern3,'<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>');
        return replacedText;
        }
```

I've added a negative lookahead to your regular expressions which make your regex ignore urls inside of HTML tags.

Comment: thank you! it works!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! my lack of understanding of how regexp works is apparent. I will train harder! *rock lee thumbs up*